# Editing new attribute to XML element using DOMDocument in PHP

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I currently have this XML document in my MVC application

```
<elements>   
   <element name="agents" path="admin/agents" scope="system">
       <folder function="model">models</folder>
       <folder function="controller">controllers</folder>
       <folder function="view">views</folder>
   </element> 
</elements>
```

I would like to add additional "visibility=hidden" attribute to the element using DOMDocument. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people use the `DOMElement::setAttribute()` or `DOMElement::setAttributeNS()` method for this.

```
$xml = <<<XML
<elements>   
   <element name="agents" path="admin/agents" scope="system"> 
     ...
   </element> 
</elements>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//element[1]') as $element) {
  $element->setAttribute('visibility', 'hidden');
}
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<elements>   
   <element name="agents" path="admin/agents" scope="system" visibility="hidden"> 
     ...
   </element> 
</elements>
```

However attributes are nodes, too. So you can create them using `DOMDocument::createAttribute()` and set using `DOMElement::setAttributeNode()`. This allows to separate the creation from the assignment.

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//element[1]') as $element) {
  $attribute = $document->createAttribute('visibility');
  $attribute->value = 'hidden';
  $element->setAttributeNode($attribute);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use [`createAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattribute.php), for example :**

```
$raw = <<<XML
<elements>   
   <element name="agents" path="admin/agents" scope="system">
       <folder function="model">models</folder>
       <folder function="controller">controllers</folder>
       <folder function="view">views</folder>
   </element> 
</elements>
XML;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($raw);

$visibility = $doc->createAttribute('visiblity');
$visibility->value = 'hidden';

$element = $doc->getElementsByTagName('element')->item(0);
$element->appendChild($visibility);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/541276)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<elements>   
   <element name="agents" path="admin/agents" scope="system" visiblity="hidden">
       <folder function="model">models</folder>
       <folder function="controller">controllers</folder>
       <folder function="view">views</folder>
   </element> 
</elements>
```